# Intellij input own color for certain words and/or symbols

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I've just installed Intellij and am using the Scala Plugin.

I downloaded a Monokai color format but I can't seem to change certain words/symbols to a certain color.

I've found where you can change colors by their type but that's all.

example `=` is red while `+=` and `++=` are blue

I would like key words to be red but I'd also like other words like `class` `object` `var` `val` `def` to be blue.

Is it possible to change the color of words by their text in Intellij?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to change the color of certain keywords, other than by writing a plugin: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7247